# Running into couple of issues kohana framework: routing and running on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, kohana, url-routing

I've started to learn kohana fews days ago and with my Zend Framework my learning experience seems to be fast until i run into couple of issues.

First of all i started the project in windows 7(dual booting with linux ubuntu 12.04). i know every link was fine before i started adding more pages to an admin app with kendo ui. i've added couple  of routes to handle controllers in subfolders and to handle url with query string of the form `?bla=dkll&second=lkdjf` (used by kendo grid to send unknown number of params based on users interaction with the grid).

**First problem** : under windows i would access any url except the root `/` eg `localhost/admin/` (admin being my folder in htdocs) it gives me

`ERROR: HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on this server` :

> 83 `try`
>   84 `{`
>   85     `if ( ! class_exists($prefix.$controller))`
>   86     `{`
>   87         `throw new HTTP_Exception_404('The requested URL :uri was not found on this server.',`
>   88             `array(':uri' => $request->uri()));`
>   89     `}`
>   90 
>   91     `// Load the controller using reflection`
>   92     `$class = new ReflectionClass($prefix.$controller);`

**Second problem** : Under ubuntu not only i have the same first problem but then i can't even hit other `urls` like `localhost/admin/useraccess/login`

**Questions:**

is the second problem related to the first one (obviously aside the '/' not found one) 
i have enabled on ubuntu mod_rewrite and the kohana install page is all green.

is there any other settings i forgot to enable which was enabled in windows php (xampp) that's not on ubuntu?

my .htaccess/logs/boostrap are found [here](http://pastie.org/4278033)

thanks for reading this and helping out

Answer (score 2):

I assume that root folder of your application is 'admin'. In bootstrap.php you should have:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'      => '/admin',
    'index_file'    => FALSE,
));
```

Also in your bootstrap.php default route should be last route:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Other routes that you add should take place above default route.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work.I've removed the forward slash `/admin` in both bootstrap and .htaccess. none of the method works.

Comment: Have you removed '#' in front of '#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so' in httpd.conf ?

Comment: Hello i haven't got to the linux yet. i'm still on windows trying to the `first question`. when i'm sure there is absolutely no problem on windows i would concentrate on linux.by the way i used `a2enmod rewrite` it should be fine ain't it? i'll check though..... thanks

Comment: well you asked 'is there any other settings i forgot to enable which was enabled in windows php (xampp) that's not on ubuntu?'. So I'm telling you that you should go in 'appache/conf' folder where you will find httpd.conf and then you should uncomment this line to enable mode rewrite. Also in Kohana bootstrap you must put 'index_file' to FALSE. Cheers.

Comment: Hello, 
in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf there is this : 
`
# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include httpd.conf
# Include ports listing
Include ports.conf
`
this line `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
` is already commented in /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load
same for `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so` in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load

Comment: The 'default' route is an example and will route you to the 'Hello, world!' message. Replacing it with more specific routes instead of keeping it as a 'catch all' route is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem with you, my kohana running well on my windows machine. but when i migrate it to Ubuntu I have a problem with routing. This is my bad, i forgot to edit my apache conf. You can look into conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
   
Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
/Directory>
```

edit 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All' and restart your apache webserver .

Works like magic !!

Answer (score 1):

To add to [digby's note](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/comment/73494#Comment_73494): [All class file names and directory names are lowercase.](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/conventions#class-names-and-file-location)

There are a few little things I noticed but nothing that could explain the problem you are having:

- [Query strings should not be and are not used to route to an action](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/request.php#L764). Use $this->request->query() in controllers to use GET values.
- Slashes get [trimed off](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/request.php#L783) the beginning and end of URI's, so the optional / in the commented out 'def' route is useless.
- The second time defining the kendogrid route overwrites the old one. Not that it really matters since they are the same, so why not remove one?

What controller do you expect to be routed too? Currently it should be Controller_... Hmm... I spy with my little eye a typo! 'susbcribers' instead of 'subscribers'. So currently you will be routed to Controller_Susbcribers::index().

If you want the Controller_Useraccess::index() instead of Controller_Subscribers::index() (assuming you fix the typo) remove the first kendogrid route since both 'kendogrid' and 'default' match an empty URI.

PS. I am assuming you use 3.2